# Why does this pointer points to wrong object inside member's constructor during object initialization?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, this

Following code prints the same address twice:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
    B()
    {
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    }
};

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    }
    
    B b;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Why does this pointer points to A inside B's constructor?

Comment: Because they are in the same space. A contains a B field first (and only in this case) so the first object in his space is the B object. The pointers are the same because the A object and the B field share the same space in the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B is an empty class and because of that is a *standard layout* class.

A contains only one (non static) member which is a B. It has no virtual methods. Because of that it is also a standard layout class.

For standard layout classes, the standard requires the address of an object to be the same of the address of its first subobject.

So it is normal that you see the same addresses, and the A object and its B subobject are pointer interconvertible.

---

**BEWARE** What follows is the original wrong answer. It is left here for reference only but is plain wrong
It is only an implementation detail. The first subobject is guaranteed to have the same address of its containing object only in standard layout classes, what neither A nor B are.

Here your implementation choosed to give both objects the same address, but another implementation could have used different addresses.

Never rely on implementation details...

Comment: `B` is empty, that's *StandardLayout*, and `A` only contains one empty non-static data member, so it is too

Comment: @Caleth: you are right and I was wrong. A has a non trivial constructor and is not a trivial class, but it has no virtual methods and is indeed standard layout. I mixed both concepts and provided a wrong answer.

Comment: No worries :) They are very similar concepts

Answer (score 0):

Both pointers have the same value, but they point to different objects. There is a `B` object *within* the `A` object, and it is the first (and only) subobject of the `A`

This is guaranteed by the standard because they are [*StandardLayoutType*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType)

- All non-static data members have the same access control

  - Vacuously true for `B`
  - True for `A`
- Has no virtual functions or virtual base classes

  - True for both `A` and `B`
- Has no non-static data members of reference type

  - True for both `A` and `B`
- All non-static data members and base classes are themselves standard layout types

  - Vacuously true for `B`
  - True for `A`
- Has no two (possibly indirect) base class subobjects of the same type

  - Vacuously true for `A` and `B`
- Has all non-static data members and bit-fields declared in the same class (either all in the derived or all in some base)

  - Vacuously true for `B`
  - True for `A`
- None of the base class subobjects has the same type as [complex conditions]

  - Vacuously true for `A` and `B`